# How do i ignore layer 20 & layer 9 in Projector via script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this piece of code which should ignore all layers except layers 20 and 9.

```
projector.ignoreLayers = ~(1<<20 & 1<<9);
```

But it makes projector to ignore every layer and marks it in inspector. Like this `(1<<20 & 1<<9)`dont exist.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Fixed it! it was ~(1<<20 | 1<<9);

Comment: You should answer your own question. This is great information!

Answer (score 0):

I just add OR (|) operator instead of AND (&).

```
projector.ignoreLayers = ~(1<<20 | 1<<9);
```

Comment: How is this different from the question?